# Protocol Buffers library-dependent location in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, protocol-buffers

I try to use `import` in my `*.proto` instructions for Protobuf. In my app, I have a few plugins with these `*.proto` instructions. But `IntelliJ` with `Protocol Buffers` marks imports and classes from the imported files as red.

I found, if I add in `Preferences->Languages & Frameworks->Protocol Buffers` strong location to my `*.proto` it will be green. But I have many places with *.proto, for example for each plugin in my app, and some of this `*.proto` can have an equal name, like `featuresDto` for each plugin. How can I add library-dependent location instead of strong?

However, the protobuf-generator works as expected.

[[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGkd5.png)]

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get correctly what do you mean by `library-dependent location` - could you please explain?

As for protobuf plugin settings: there you can find all **directories**, where you'll be able to import files from. E.g. if the protobuf file is located in `/foo/bar/MyService.proto`, and you want to be able to import it as `import "bar/MyService.proto";`, you should add `/foo/` directory to the plugin settings.
In fact those settings mean exactly the same as directories one specifies with `proto-path` cli argument: if any proto file can not be resolved against one of given proto-paths, compilation will not succeed.

Also you may find useful the following issues about simplifying solving imports-related problems: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-283099 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-283097

Comment: Clarifying questions are better suited for comments, and should not be included in your answer. (Acknowledging that you don’t yet have enough reputation to leave comments.)